# Oracle DB Audit ALL

Tags: oracle, audit

I have a 5TB large database.

I want to audit everything , really everything.

First of all, I tried with `AUDIT ALL`, but according to [Oracle's document `AUDIT ALL does NOT` audit everything](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm#BABEFEAC)...

I know that this statement must be executed in order to start auditing db:

```
 alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;
```

But what else should I do to start auditing all the SQL statements that users execute?

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use the AUDIT feature if you only want a view on user queries (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`) on your database.  `$AUD` contains rather ***DDL statements***, whereas `V$SQL` contains only ***DML statements***.

A very simple solution is to use another view: [***`V$SQL`***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246). You can extract duration and lot of useful info from it.

Useful example:

```
  SELECT * FROM v$sql vv
   WHERE lower(vv.SQL_TEXT) like '%delete%'
     AND vv.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME like 'A_SCHEMA%'
ORDER BY  vv.LAST_ACTIVE_TIME desc;
```

> `V$SQL` lists statistics on shared `SQL` area without the `GROUP BY` clause and contains one row for each child of the original SQL text entered. Statistics displayed in `V$SQL` are normally updated at the end of query execution.

Long running queries  are updated every 5 seconds. This shows the impact of long running SQLs while they are still working.

Comment: So basically there's no difference beetwen records stored in the view V$SQL and $AUD table ? Except if I was interested in auditing sessions (conection times etc), which I am not interested at.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. For **your purpose**, you could check what's in `V$SQL`. It is different. `$AUD` would contain ***DDL statements***, whereas `V$SQL` would contain ***DML statements***.